# An Assortment of Letters

Tags: language, letters

Can you figure out how I've split the below letters into their groups?

| Group 1 | Group 2 |
| --- | --- |
| D H L S | F P T Y |

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C D H J N P V W Y | L T M | S B R |

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B S | T R | C | D | L |

Happy Puzzling!

**Hint 1:**

> The letters are all pronounced similarly, but it's the difference that's key...

Comment: Can we assume that letters which are not shown in the puzzle cannot be classified in any of the groups (hence that's why they are missing)?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact reason why they were omitted.